# How to check backlog of sessions at Vertica?

Tags: vertica

Is there a way in Vertica to check backlog of sessions? For example - to check what sessions were active 6-12-24 hours ago? 2-4-10 days ago?

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: select * from sessions; - shows only current;
v_monitor.query_requests - does not have a long backlog

Comment: Please edit your question.

Comment: Increase the retention time for query_requests and/or save it in a permanent table...

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into you DC retention policy.

**You can start by looking at the policy definition using :**

`select get_data_collector_policy('SessionStarts');`

**Also you got this components responsible for sessions:**

```
`dbadmin=> SELECT distinct component  FROM data_collector where component ilike '%session%';
     component
-------------------
 SessionStarts
 SessionParameters
 SessionEnds
`
```

**See more details on this page:**

[**How to Manage and Work with Data Collector in Vertica**](http://www.aodba.com/managing-and-working-with-data-collector-in-vertica/)